# Highcharts Line Chart - Some categories are not visible

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've been using the `highcharts` package to display an audiogram, my categories `array` is

`['0.125' ,'0.250', '0.5, '0.750' , '1', '1.5', '2', '3', '4', '6', '8', '9', '11.2' , '12.5', '14', '16', '18', '20']`

But when the chart is not wide enough (*e.g.* when I put 2 charts side by side), some categories `( 0.250 , 0.750, 1.5 ....)` become hidden as you can see in the image below:   [image: []

What I need is *all* the categories to be shown despite the chart width, like this one:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:
  http://jsfiddle.net/5cbroe1f/
Here's the fiddle, both charts have the same data. As I said before, I need all the categories to be shown in the first chart (the smaller one).

Thanks!

Comment: I believe that this is a default setting of HighCharts to keep the charts clear! Else you're datapoints will overlap and it won't be clear anymore. I think the best way to prevent this, is to place a `max-width` attribute in the `div` linked to the charts.

Comment: Any chance you could put together a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) showing your attempt? Without anything more detailed than a couple photos, it is difficult to assist.

Comment: Hello @AnnaJeanine, thanks for the fast answer. But when I set the max-width, the same thing happens, some categories become invisible.

Comment: @abenrob, nice advice, i'll edit the original question with the jsfiddle

Comment: Most of the [highcharts demos](http://www.highcharts.com/demo) have a link to a fiddle, which might give a head-start.

Comment: I believe that setting xAxis.labels.step = 1 should work for you. It should display every label but the labels will overlapp if they are too close. Other options to consider staggerLines/rotation.

Comment: @abenrob I've just updated the question adding the fiddle :)

Comment: @morganfree It works !  Thanks ! How can I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: I posted the answer, you can accept it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying each category's label you need to set [xAxis.labels.step](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.step) to 1.

```
xAxis: {
  categories: [],
  labels: {
    step: 1
  }
},
```